# Настройка полей

Tags: latex

Я только начал изучать LaTex и столкнулся с такой проблемой: как отдельно настроить поля и нарисовать рамку вокруг страницы, причем рамка не должна зависеть от полей. В word это делается очень просто. Как мне в LaTex сделать, к примеру, поля страницы по 2см, а рамка имела верхнее и нижнее поля по 7пт, а правое и левое - 9пт?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Допустим, в word есть документ, у которого все поля настроены по 2см, и по краям страницы есть рамка, у которой верхнее и нижнее поле 7пт, а правое и левое - 9пт. Вот я хочу сделать страницу с такими же настройками, но в LaTex

Answer (score 3):

В LaTeX это делается тоже довольно просто. Для настройки полей документа удобно использовать пакет `geometry`: он позволяет задавать самые экзотические конфигурации, в том числе и такие, как требуют в издательствах (когда привязка идет не к размеру бумаги, а под параметры издательского оборудования). Настоятельно рекомендую хотя бы ознакомиться с его документацией, чтобы уметь пользоваться его возможностями. А саму рамку мне удобнее рисовать с помощью пакета `tikz` (но можно использовать и другие средства). Пакет `lipsum` с одноименной командой использован только для того, чтобы чем-то заполнить страницу.

Раз понадобилась несимметричная рамка, то я сделал ее в виде макроса с 4 обязательными параметрами, которые задают отступ от каждой границы, и одним необязательным - со значением по умолчанию (он идет первым и задается в прямоугольных скобках). В примере я привел оба варианта использования - без опционального параметра и с ним. При необходимости, цвет и стиль линий рамки также можно изменить (для указания цвета линий в макросе я привел команду).

В итоге, для работы всего этого нужны пакеты `geometry` и `tikz`, а к последнему еще необходима библиотека `calc`. Размер и тип документа не должен влиять на работу макроса (лишь бы заказанные отступы к рамке позволяли вписать прямоугольник в этот размер).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {calc}

% #1 - толщина линии, задается со значением по умолчанию, можно не указывать при вызове макроса
% #2 - величина отступа слева от границы бумаги
% #3 - отступ справа
% #4 - отступ сверху
% #5 - отступ снизу
\newcommand{\ramka}[5][0.7pt]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[line width=#1,color=black] ($(current page.south west) + (#2,#5)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east) - (#3,#4)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \ramka{9mm}{15mm}{7mm}{7mm}
    \ramka[10pt]{3cm}{3cm}{4cm}{4cm}
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Результат работы должен быть примерно таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]